# Append bytes to NSInputStream to be read later sequentially

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsstream

I am getting chunks of `NSData` sequentially from server, more than approx. `4096` bytes at a time, sequentially. Each received chunk may differ in its size.

What I would like to do, is to append all these bytes somewhere, and at the same time start reading from the beginning of the data, **sequentially**, **512 bytes at a time** maximum.

While searching I've learned about using `NSInputStream` for this, and here is the code snippet:

```
        uint8_t bytes[512];
        UInt32 length;

        NSInputStream *stream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:aData];
        [stream open];
        while (((length = [stream read:bytes maxLength:512]) > 0)) {
            if ([self.inputStreamer isKindOfClass:[PLAudioInputStreamerNoOpenClose class]]) {
                [self.inputStreamer hasData:bytes length:length];
            }
        }
```

While this just works, the initialized `NSInputStream` does not seem to allow appending additional bytes after it is initialized, so the only way I could think of is, to initialize `NSInputStreams` for every chunk of data, and block until it has reached its end, going on to do the same for next chunk of bytes, as the code above does.

Is there any more preferred solution for this kind of task? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: If your are a Korean speaker, please follow 'Stack Overflow in Korean' proposal. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68765/stack-overflow-in-korean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 'read and write' stream. `NSInputStream` is read only and `NSOutputStream` is write only.

If I were you, I just use a NSMutableData and one int variables for 'current reading position'.

```
NSMutableData* myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSInteger myPos = 0;

[myData appendData:..];
...
// need to check the range (myPos ~ [myData length])
NSData* nextBlockToRead = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:((char*)[myData bytes] + myPos) length:512];
myPos += 512;
```

Comment: You need a 'read and write' stream -> how you can have a 'read and write' stream? i have the same issue as OP (i need a stream not NSMutableData)

Comment: @PeterLapisu Not NSMutableData, maybe NSFileHandle? There are many ways to do file input/output, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH5-SW1